# How to delete *.vmdk files?

Tags: macos, rm

I can't seem to delete `*.vmdk` files and related on Mac OS X 10.6.8 with `sudo rm`:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /Volumes/Temp/vm/
rm: /Volumes/Temp/vm//MarukoVM/nvram: Read-only file system
rm: /Volumes/Temp/vm//MarukoVM/vmware.log: Read-only file system
rm: /Volumes/Temp/vm//MarukoVM/Windows XP Professional-f001.vmdk: Read-only file system
rm: /Volumes/Temp/vm//MarukoVM/Windows XP Professional-f002.vmdk: Read-only file system
rm: /Volumes/Temp/vm//MarukoVM/Windows XP Professional-f003.vmdk: Read-only file system
rm: /Volumes/Temp/vm//MarukoVM/Windows XP Professional.vmdk: Read-only file system
rm: /Volumes/Temp/vm//MarukoVM/Windows XP Professional.vmsd: Read-only file system
rm: /Volumes/Temp/vm//MarukoVM/Windows XP Professional.vmx: Read-only file system
```

How to delete them?

Comment: gee, I wonder if the error "Read-only file system" means anything?

Comment: Let me guess, NTFS disk?